# Modify chrome extension to trigger by two finger double click instead of one finger double click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to modify this extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-on-doubleclick/jkmalmidnicnnmceielaelokkdmmgkcb?hl=en

It zooms on double click. I want it to zoom on two finger double click.
I'm using a macbook trackpad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible now, Chrome does not support gestures from trackpad now. The only possible workaround is to translate the gesture to rarely used shortcut and handle this shortcut in a fixed version of the extension